# Select sum of condition

Tags: sql

I have a table like below. I want to select some rows that sum of cnt<120. how to do this?

```
cnt  id
_________
6   14001
17  14005
14  14017
16  14024
9   14025
7   14027
10  14029
14  14048
23  14055
18  14056
19  14058
18  14059
18  14063
15  14064
9   14086
17  14095
9   14098
14  14116
10  14138
8   14147
17  14165
22  14171
22  14191
18  14194
13  14204
17  14221
13  14245
14  14249
6   14254
17  14257
9   14260
19  14261
26  14263
6   14264
27  14265
19  14269
11  14287
```

Comment: You have to decide how to select. First/last rows, smallest, how many etc.

Comment: Please add the output you expect, the query you tried and a little more explanation what you try to do

Comment: Start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM   my_table
WHERE  cnt < 120
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM test O
HAVING (SELECT sum(cnt) FROM test WHERE cnt <= O.cnt) <120
```